# IF/AND between two dates Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I am trying to implement the following logic but my formulas are not encompassing all possibilities.

Am I able to accomplish the following using the approach outlined below?

```
C5 has a start date(yy/mm/dd), 2013-10-01.
D5 has an end date(yy/mm/dd),2013-10-23.
F3->CX2 has 7 cells merged with the monday's date in the cell.
```

Example: F3: `30-Sep-13`, M3: `07-Oct-13`, T3: `14-Oct-13`.

F4->CX4 and below are the unmerged seven cells, therefore you have seven cells below each week cell.

My goal is to use Conditional Formatting when cell has value TRUE to fill the background colour of each individual cell between the start and the end date. However I am having trouble determining the correct formula.  I have tried the following in F4 and across and below but none have proven to work for all scenario's:

`F4=AND(C5=F3, D5>=F3)  F5=AND(C5=(F3+1), D5>=(F3+1))...`

only fills the cell for the start date not all the cells between the start and end date.

In short, I need to identify the start cell and fill it, continue filling all cells until the end date.

Should this be a macro with a while loop?

---

***I Believe I have solved my question with the following formula:

`=IF(AND((F3)>=$C$5,(F3)<=$D$5),TRUE,FALSE)`, `=IF(AND((F3+1)>=$C$5,(F3+1)<=$D$5),TRUE,FALSE)`, `=IF(AND((F3+2)>=$C$5,(F3+2)<=$D$5),TRUE,FALSE)`...Then after 7 cells it becomes: `=IF(AND((M3+1)>=$C$5,(M3+1)<=$D$5),TRUE,FALSE)`, `=IF(AND((M3+1)>=$C$5,(M3+1)<=$D$5),TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: Are you using this formula in an individual cell, or as part of the conditional formatting Format Conditions/rules?

Comment: I am putting a formula in the cell that will return TRUE/FALSE, then conditional formatting based on the TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: @pnuts, sorry that's CX4,it corresponds to 30-Dec-2013

Comment: Please don't try to put formulas or code in the comments...

Comment: I think you are trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be. Excel's Conditional Formatting in versions 2007+ (and maybe 2003, I don't remember) supports "Between" logic for format conditions.  See my suggestion, below.

Comment: @pnuts only highlighting, the IF retruns true or false then the conditional formatting is IF Cell Value is True Highlight, IF Cell Value is False do not highlight. F3 and seven cells to the right are merged however the seven cells below are not this simulates seven individual days with the monday of the week as the "label".

Comment: @pnuts  Here is a prettier version of what I am trying to do: [link](http://www.google.ca/imgres?sa=X&biw=1280&bih=911&tbm=isch&tbnid=W4Sm8GX8Kj2ztM:&imgrefurl=http://www.sharewarebay.com/Business/Project_Management/Gantt_Project/index1.html&docid=Wsip0LGOoqzhOM&imgurl=http://www.sharewarebay.com/images/screenshot/jxproject_company/jxProject.gif&w=800&h=600&ei=skRgUs3TG4Wl4AOul4BQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=2&vpy=423&dur=219&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=148&ty=104&page=2&tbnh=142&tbnw=190&start=29&ndsp=34&ved=1t:429,r:57,s:0,i:256)

Comment: ugggh. Good luck. You're trying to build a Gantt chart in a spreadsheet application. Consider using a PM tool like Microsoft Project, etc.

Comment: @ David Zemens ugghh is right...

Answer (score 1):

> Should this be a macro with a while loop?

It seems it does not have to be, though that depends upon my interpretation of your question, which seems odd if only because the conditions are not in the rows for which they trigger the formatting.

Select the applicable range starting in F4 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND($F$3+COLUMN()-6>=$C5,$F$3+COLUMN()-6<=$D5)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, OK, OK.

[image: SO19435562 example]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stepwise view on the problem as I see it:

1. Set up your data and include the actual date of your "weekly view" as part of the sheet:

   [image]
2. Add conditional formatting to a single cell (say, Monday of Week 1) that applies to "a formula to determine which cells to format":

   [image]
3. Copy-and-Paste-formats to the remainder of the cells:

   [image]

   The result should resemble:

   [image]
4. Change the actual cell formatting to `""` to remove the date from view:

   [image]

The removes the capability to insert any content in the cells (but that wasn't part of the question). If you want to insert content and maintain colouring, you can base the conditional formatting on a similar-sized/shaped layout elsewhere in the sheet and format it accordingly. For example, the following layout provides this yet allows you to enter content in the conditionally formatted area:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula conditions.  I put a start date in A1, and an end date in A2. Modify as needed per your requirements.

Then I will apply conditional formatting to values in range E1:E6.  Again, modify as per your requirements.

[image]

Then simply use `Highlight cells Rules > Between`

[image]

Then, select your start/end values and press OK.  Voila!

[image]